# Jquery refer to a dom input with null value

Tags: jquery, dom

Im trying to refer to all inputs with nill value. Tried with below code and failed. I was trying to change its css thats wy used .css

```
$("('input').val()=''").css('border','1px solid red');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not valid to put JS function calls inside a string for use as a selector.

What you can do is select all inputs and then use the [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the set to only those with a blank value:

```js
$('input').filter(function() {
  return this.value === '';
}).css('border','1px solid red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="Pineapple"> <input value=""> <input value="Orange">
<input value=""> <input value="Mango"> <input value="Lime">
```

You may want to use `return $.trim(this.value) === ''` if fields with space characters in them count as empty for your purposes.